# OpenGL reconstructing eye-view position from linearized depth incorrect

Tags: c++, opengl, deferred-rendering

i have been trying to implement deferred rendering for past 2 weeks. I have finally come to the spot lighting pass part using stencil buffer and linearized depth. I hold 3 framebuffer textures : albedo, normal+depth (X,Y,Z,EyeViewLinearDepth), Lighting texture. So I draw my light (sphere) and apply this fragment shader :

```
void main(void)
{
  vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy * u_inverseScreenSize.xy;

  float linearDepth = texture2D(u_normalDepth, texCoord.st).a;

  // vector to far plane
  vec3 viewRay = vec3(v_vertex.xy * (-farClip/v_vertex.z), -farClip);
  // scale viewRay by linear depth to get view space position
  vec3 vertex = viewRay * linearDepth;

  vec3 normal = texture2D(u_normalDepth, texCoord.st).xyz*2.0 - 1.0;

  vec4 ambient = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  vec4 diffuse = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  vec4 specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  vec3 lightDir = lightpos - vertex ;
  vec3 R = normalize(reflect(lightDir, normal));
  vec3 V = normalize(vertex);

  float lambert = max(dot(normal, normalize(lightDir)), 0.0);

  if (lambert > 0.0) {
    float distance = length(lightDir);
    if (distance <= u_lightRadius) {  

      //CLASSICAL LIGHTING COMPUTATION PART
    }
  }


  vec4 final_color = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(final_color.xyz,  1.0);

}
```

The variables you need to know : v_vertex is eye space position of the vertex (of sphere), lightpos is the position/center of the light in eye space, linearDepth is generated on geometry pass stage in eye space.

The problem is that, the code fail this if check : `if (distance <= u_lightRadius)`. The light is never computed until i remove the distance check. I am sure that i pass these values correctly, radius is 170.0, light position is only like 40-50 units away from the model. There is definitely something wrong but i can't find it somehow. I tried many possibilities of radius and other variables.

Comment: If you suspect you're not properly re-constructing the viewspace position, you should add a 4th buffer temporarily to store the viewspace position as computed during your G-Buffer creation phase, then make a stripped down version of your existing shader that does nothing but reconstruct the viewspace position. Write this position to gl_FragColor and then compare the result with the actual position G-Buffer. You might consider blitting the results of both to different halves of your viewport for quick comparison, or fill the entire viewport and alternate every hundred msecs. or so..

Comment: Then work with that shader until you get the results identical. Sounds like common sense, I know - but debugging shaders, particularly in deferred shading requires a little bit of creativity. If they're already identical, you can rule the reconstruction out and focus your effort elsewhere.